# Django SessionWizardView current step missing from form_list after Ajax request

Tags: python, django, session

I've got a `SessionWizardView` process with conditional extra steps which at the end of the first step essentially asks 'do you want to add another person' so my condition is generated by checking the cleaned data for the previous step;

```
def function_factory(prev_step):
    """ Creates the functions for the condition dict controlling the additional
    entrant steps in the process.

    :param prev_step: step in the signup process to check
    :type prev_step: unicode
    :return: additional_entrant()
    :rtype:
    """
    def additional_entrant(wizard):
        """
        Checks the cleaned_data for the previous step to see if another entrant
        needs to be added
        """
        # try to get the cleaned data of prev_step
        cleaned_data = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step(prev_step) or {}

        # check if the field ``add_another_person`` was checked.
        return cleaned_data.get(u'add_another_person', False)

    return additional_entrant

def make_condition_stuff(extra_steps, last_step_before_repeat):
    cond_funcs = {}
    cond_dict = {}
    form_lst = [
        (u"main_entrant", EntrantForm),
    ]

    for x in range(last_step_before_repeat, extra_steps):
        key1 = u"{}_{}".format(ADDITIONAL_STEP_NAME, x)
        if x == 1:
            prev_step = u"main_entrant"
        else:
            prev_step = u"{}_{}".format(ADDITIONAL_STEP_NAME, x-1)
        cond_funcs[key1] = function_factory(prev_step)
        cond_dict[key1] = cond_funcs[key1]
        form_lst.append(
            (key1, AdditionalEntrantForm)
        )

    form_lst.append(
        (u"terms", TermsForm)
    )

    return cond_funcs, cond_dict, form_lst

last_step_before_extras = 1
extra_steps = settings.ADDITIONAL_ENTRANTS

cond_funcs, cond_dict, form_list = make_condition_stuff(
    extra_steps,
    last_step_before_extras
)
```

I've also got a dictionary which stores step data behind a key accessible via the session cookie, which also holds a list of the people's details entered by a user. After the first form, this list is rendered as a select box & on selection triggers an Ajax call to the `SessionWizard` with kwargs which triggers the call to a method which returns a `JsonResponse`;

```
class SignupWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'entrant/wizard_form.html'
    form_list = form_list
    condition_dict = cond_dict
    model = Entrant
    main_entrant = None
    data_dict = dict()

    def get_data(self, source_step, step):
        session_data_dict = self.get_session_data_dict()
        try:
            data = session_data_dict[source_step].copy()
            data['event'] = self.current_event.id
            for key in data.iterkeys():
                if step not in key:
                    newkey = u'{}-{}'.format(step, key)
                    data[newkey] = data[key]
                    del data[key]
        except (KeyError, RuntimeError):
            data = dict()
            data['error'] = (
                u'There was a problem retrieving the data you requested. '
                u'Please resubmit the form if you would like to try again.'
            )

        response = JsonResponse(data)
        return response

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(SignupWizard, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs
        )
        if 'get_data' in kwargs:
            data_id = kwargs['get_data']
            step = kwargs['step']
            response = self.get_data(data_id, step)

        # update the response (e.g. adding cookies)
        self.storage.update_response(response)
        return response

    def process_step(self, form):
        form_data = self.get_form_step_data(form)
        current_step = self.storage.current_step or ''
        session_data_dict = self.get_session_data_dict()

        if current_step in session_data_dict:
            # Always replace the existing data for a step.
            session_data_dict.pop(current_step)

        if not isinstance(form, TermsForm):
            entrant_data = dict()
            fields_to_remove = [
                'email', 'confirm_email', 'password',
                'confirm_password', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
            ]
            for k, v in form_data.iteritems():
                entrant_data[k] = v
            for field in fields_to_remove:
                if '{}-{}'.format(current_step, field) in entrant_data:
                    entrant_data.pop('{}-{}'.format(current_step, field))
                if '{}'.format(field) in entrant_data:
                    entrant_data.pop('{}'.format(field))

            for k in entrant_data.iterkeys():
                new_key = re.sub('{}-'.format(current_step), u'', k)
                entrant_data[new_key] = entrant_data.pop(k)

            session_data_dict[current_step] = entrant_data
            done = False
            for i, data in enumerate(session_data_dict['data_list']):
                if data[0] == current_step:
                    session_data_dict['data_list'][i] = (
                        current_step, u'{} {}'.format(
                            entrant_data['first_name'],
                            entrant_data['last_name']
                        )
                    )
                    done = True

            if not done:
                session_data_dict['data_list'].append(
                    (
                        current_step, u'{} {}'.format(
                            entrant_data['first_name'],
                            entrant_data['last_name']
                        )
                    )
                )

        return form_data
```

If you step through the form without triggering the Ajax call then the form submits and the condition dict behaves as expected. But if the Ajax is triggered and the data is returned to the form, once you submit the form the session data appears to have gone. Is there a way to change the way I've got this setup so that `get_data()` can return the data to the page, without destroying the session?

I've got the `SESSION_ENGINE` set to `cached_db` on a dev server but I've got an issue whereby when you submit the first conditional form and the system calls `get_next_step()` followed by `get_form_list()` and the condition check no longer returns that first conditional form so I'm left with my default form list and a `ValueError` raised because `current_step` is no longer part of `form_list`.

So, to recap, I step through my first form, trigger the first conditional form using the 'add_another_person' field which renders the form as expected at which point `form_list` looks like this;

```
form_list   
    u'main_entrant' <class 'online_entry.forms.EntrantForm'>
    u'additional_entrant_1' <class 'online_entry.forms.EntrantForm'>
    u'terms' <class 'online_entry.forms.TermsForm'>
```

But as soon as `additional_entrant_1` triggers the Ajax method, then is submitted, the `form_list` runs through the condition dict & looks like this;

```
form_list   
    u'main_entrant' <class 'online_entry.forms.EntrantForm'>
    u'terms' <class 'online_entry.forms.TermsForm'>
```

Could this be an issue with the session storage or the session becoming invalid?

Comment: Conditions used to determine if a step is included or not in the wizard should be consistent throughout the wizard. I mean, you can decide for further steps but not for previous steps. Check if your condition for a previous step is suddenly changing on a further step.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña I would consider my conditions to be consistent, the first form has the same field & therefore condition as the remainder until the last form as that's just a terms & conditions checkbox. Is it possible that `wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step()` might not return data as expected every time?

Comment: I don't think so. Are your step conditions based on information collected in the same wizard, or external parameters?

Comment: @LorenzoPeña The conditions are based on information in the wizard form. There's a boolean field, displayed as a checkbox on all, apart from the last, wizard step. It's that field that each condition gets from the cleaned data of the previous step.

Comment: Debugging tip: try printing the result of `get_cleaned_data_for_step` for every step, on every step. If the condition stops evaluating to true, then the data is changed somehow. This could help determine where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always overlook the simple explanation.

The `get()` request of the `SessionWizardView` resets the storage, and the Ajax call I was making hit the view as a get request, resetting the storage, but also passing back my information.

So with a simple override of the `get()` method I've resolved this;

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'get_data' in kwargs:
        data_id = kwargs['get_data']
        step = kwargs['step']
        response = self.get_data(data_id, step)
    else:
        self.storage.reset()

        # reset the current step to the first step.
        self.storage.current_step = self.steps.first
        response = self.render(self.get_form())
    return response
```